# Chrome runtime on web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have noticed that some sites allowed to use chrome.runtime API on their pages without any extensions and some doesn't. Checked this via console.

What is the reason of different behaviour?

Regards,
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

chrome.runtime available if you connect site via https protocol